# browser cache api in GCP GKE

Tags: reactjs, docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, mern

I have developed a React TypeScript Vite project that utilizes the browser Cache API for caching API responses. After successfully building the project using npm run build, I containerized the resulting dist folder with Nginx for server deployment. The application functions correctly on both my local machine and when deployed on Docker. However, when attempting to host it on Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE), I encounter an error stating that "caches is not defined." I am seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue.